# Compressing a file using zip or gzip

Tags: java, beginner, compression

> Write a Compress class defines two static methods, gzipFile(), which
>   compresses a file using GZIP compression format, and zipDirectory(),
>   which compresses the files (but not directories) in a directory using
>   the ZIP archive and compression format. gzipFile() uses the
>   GZIPOutputStream class, while zipDirectory() uses the ZipOutputStream
>   and ZipEntry classes, all from java.util.zip.

I am outputting the compressed file in the same directory as the input file.
For `zipDirectory()` method I have recursively found out the files present in the directory(including those in the sub directories), stored them in a `List<File>`, and added them to the zip.
How can I improve this code?

```
package beg_assignment8;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;

public class Compress {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int op = sc.nextInt();
        String source = sc.next();
        switch (op) {
        case 1:
            GZIPFile(source);
            break;
        case 2:
            zipDirectory(source);
            break;
        }
    }

    public static void GZIPFile(String sourcePath) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        File file = new File(sourcePath);
        String destPath = sourcePath + ".gz";


        try (
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destPath);
            GZIPOutputStream gzos = new GZIPOutputStream(fos)
        ) {
            writeFileToOutputStream(file, gzos);
        }
    }

    public static void zipDirectory(String sourcePath) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        File dir = new File(sourcePath);
        List<File> allFiles = getAllFiles(dir);
        String destPath = sourcePath + ".zip";

        try (
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destPath);
            ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos)
        ) {
            for (File file : allFiles) {
                String zipFile =
                    file.getCanonicalPath().substring(dir.getCanonicalPath()
                            .length() + 1);
                ZipEntry ze = new ZipEntry(zipFile);
                zos.putNextEntry(ze);
                writeFileToOutputStream(file, zos);
                zos.closeEntry();
            }
        }
    }

    private static List<File> getAllFiles(File dir) {
        File[] files = dir.listFiles();
        List<File> allFiles = new ArrayList<>();
        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                List<File> allFilesRecur = getAllFiles(file);
                allFiles.addAll(allFilesRecur);
            } else {
                allFiles.add(file);
            }
        }
        return allFiles;
    }

    private static void writeFileToOutputStream(File file,
            OutputStream os) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        try (
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis)
        ) {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int nBytesRead;
            while ((nBytesRead = bis.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) >= 0) {
                os.write(buffer);
            } 
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## `nBytesRead` ignored!

> ```
>         int nBytesRead;
>         while ((nBytesRead = bis.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) >= 0) {
>             os.write(buffer);
>         }
> ```

You forgot to use the `nBytesRead` variable when writing to the other stream, putting garbage data in the target file.

```
        int nBytesRead;
        while ((nBytesRead = bis.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) >= 0) {
            os.write(buffer, 0, nBytesRead);
        }
```

## `zipDirectory()` throws a NPE

Your code throws a NullPointerException if the directory doesn't exists. (Caused by `dir.listFiles();` returning null, failing the for loop after)

You should check if `dir.exists` is true, before continuing with the method, and throw a FileNotFoundException if it is false.

## Possible IndexOutOfBoundsException

> ```
> String zipFile = file.getCanonicalPath().substring(dir.getCanonicalPath()
>                         .length() + 1);
> ```

While this line usually works correctly, it fails on unix systems if the file is symlinked to a directory with less characters, this will throw a IndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: Don't check `dir.exists` (permissions, time races, etc, may still lead to `listFiles()` failure). Correct way it to check `dir.listFiles()` return value.